# Get Sharepoint 2010 search results using Javascript Client Object Model

Tags: search, javascript, client-object-model, fast-search

I need Sharepoint search results from Cient Object model using javascript Client object model.
Can anyone please tell me how to do it for sharepoint 2010

Comment: In 2010 you would have to use the Search Web Service. search.asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search is not covered in JSOM for SP2010 - try using spservices: http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/

Comment: Thanks. i am getting this error on firing select command<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"><Response domain=""><Status>ERROR_SERVER</Status><DebugErrorMessage>System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException</DebugErrorMessage></Response></ResponsePacket

Comment: open a new Question for this